# cache external responses

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, cache

Is it possible to set up an caching proxy server to cache responses back to our system(s) from an external service that we use. My first thought is some sort of caching reverse proxy mechanism where our servers are the clients.

If so can someone please recommend a starting place. I can do research and as further questions as long as I know a place to start. Thanks for your patience.

Background: Currently we have multiple servers from our side making calls to an external service. We'd like to have the call go through the proxy, and have that proxy cache the responses we get. We want to avoid the need for one of our servers to hit the external service if another of our servers has already received a response to the same request.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible - in fact, it's what I've usually thought of as the primary motivator behind implementation of Squid. Which is (IMHO) as good a starting place as any, though I would caution you to be very careful of settign in Squid or any other cache mechanism you choose to use.